# Is it possible to keep the "Ctrl" button turned on without holding down the button?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Any way in Windows 7 64-bit to keep the Ctrl key activated for a period of time without continuously pressing the key?  I want to cut and paste several files at once but want to do it with just one hand.  Don't ask why. LOL.

Comment: isnt' there an accessibility feature called sticky keys or something built into windows?

Comment: Stickykeys is for shift.

Comment: To clarify, are looking for a function similar to `CAPS LOCK`, but for `CTRL`?

Comment: Yes, like Caps.

Comment: Not a proper answer, but get a keyboard or mouse you can code macros into - then you can set that key to do the same thing as ctrl - z, or even do a more complex sequence of keystrokes with one press.

Comment: "... do it with just one hand. Don't ask why."  -_-

Answer (score 7):

I assume Windows 7 still has [sticky keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StickyKeys).

> StickyKeys is an accessibility feature to help computer users who have physical disabilities... It essentially serializes keystrokes instead of pressing multiple keys at a time: **StickyKeys allows the user to press and release a modifier key**, such as Shift, Ctrl, Alt, or the Windows key, **and have it remain active until any other key is pressed**.

Just press shift 5 times in a row for a dialogue to enable.

Comment: [Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Make-the-keyboard-easier-to-use) *does* have StickyKeys. :)

Comment: @iglvzx Awesome! :-)

Comment: I thought that OP would need to press it again for every file.

Comment: I use Sticky Keys already but I have to press it each time before copying a file.  Looking for a one press solution.

Comment: Oh you mean you want to ctrl+c a file, ctrl+c a second file, then ctrl+v paste both somewhere? If so, that's not the way the clipboard works. @surfasb has the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try turning on checkboxes in Explorer. You can then click the checkboxes to select files.

[image]

Comment: But then I will have to check off each file with the mouse, right.  Trying to avoid too much clickity-clackety. *wink*

Comment: @verve: You can also use the  Arrow Keys and then <kbd>Space</kbd> to check them off. It doesn't get much more hands free than this.  Well short of Voice Commands.

Answer (score 2):

How about this one. Purely one-hand solution. Requires a mouse.

[image]

- Start On-Screen Keyboard from windows accessibility package
- Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in the on-screen keyboard
- Your <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is not pressed and will remain in that state until you either click it again or click another non-modified key on the keyboard
- Click on all files you want to select
- Click <kbd>C</kbd> in the on-screen keyboard
- You have now performed your copy (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) and you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is now released
- Navigate to destination directory
- Right-click and paste (either via context menu, or by means of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> on your on-screen keyboard)

Done!

Answer (score 0):

What about ignoring the mouse and using only the keyboard to do this?

- **To make a non-contiguous selection:** Use the arrow keys to move to the first file you want to select.  Now, hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and continue using the arrow keys to move to the files you want and press <kbd>Space</kbd> to select each one.
- **To make a contiguous (range) selection:** As above, use the arrow keys to move to the first file you want to select, then hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and use the arrow keys to move to the last file in the range.  Now let go of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

You can also combine the mouse and keyboard, e.g. click the first file you want to select, now hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click the last file and you'll get a contiguous selection.

Comment: Very useful for a mouse-free experience. Thanks but right now I wabt a one hand solution.